# Match Against no results

Tags: mysql, database

I have an issue with a full text search in a MySQL table.

`MATCH AGAINST` returns no results even I if have 7 records containing the words I'm looking for. What can I do to make it return the rows?

```
SELECT * 
FROM site_plugin_products_cache_texts 
WHERE MATCH(item_text) AGAINST ('+your +name' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

> No rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM site_plugin_products_cache_texts 
WHERE item_text LIKE'%your name%'
```

> 7 rows (0.071 s)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70c3fa/1/0

Thanks.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8e27/1 seems to work fine, we'll need more information to help I think

Comment: Please don't cross-post [the same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/205903/11651) to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those words are included in the [Stopwords for MyISAM Search Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), which is essentially a list of words to completely ignore in fulltext indexing (as typically they tend to occur too frequently).

The simplest solution would be to switch to InnoDB as your engine, as it has a much shorter list of stopwords.  If you need to use MyISAM, you will have to do the following:

> To override the default stopword list for MyISAM tables, set the ft_stopword_file system variable. (See Section 5.1.7, “Server System Variables”.) The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: @Emanuel Always read the manual again when a feature/operator doesn't work as expected.